# How to merge three or more Audio/Video Files in ffmpeg with Picture in Picture

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a single video file with multiple Picture in Picture (PIP for short). I was able to get two picture in a pictures working. I am now trying to add a 4th input.

What I am hoping it will look like:

[image: Mockup Image Example]

My Attempted Command:

```
ffmpeg -i 444_remote_0.webm -i 444_remote_1.webm -i 444_remote_2.webm \
       -i 444_local_0.webm -filter_complex \
       "[1:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem1]; \
        [2:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem2]; \
        [3:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[loc0]; \
        [0:v][loc0]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[bg]; \
        [bg][rem1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-180:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]; \
        [bg][rem2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-360:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]; \
        [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" \
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac 444.mp4
```

I am getting a new error: `Invalid stream specifier: bg.`

Console Output:

```
ffmpeg -i 444_remote_0.webm -i 444_remote_1.webm -i 444_remote_2.webm -i 444_local_0.webm -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem1]; [2:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem2]; [3:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[loc0]; [0:v][loc0]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[bg]; [bg][rem1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-180:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]; [bg][rem2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-360:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]; [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac 444.mp4
ffmpeg version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '444_remote_0.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Input #1, matroska,webm, from '444_remote_1.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #1:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Input #2, matroska,webm, from '444_remote_2.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #2:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Input #3, matroska,webm, from '444_local_0.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #3:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
[matroska,webm @ 0x35f5c40] Invalid stream specifier: bg.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream specifier 'bg' in filtergraph description [1:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem1]; [2:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem2]; [3:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[loc0]; [0:v][loc0]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[bg]; [bg][rem1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-180:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]; [bg][rem2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-360:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]; [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a] matches no streams.
```

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from your last command (without `-loglevel fatal`).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks for the input, I had not realized it was appropriate to post that much in the message.  I've edited my original post with the full console output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Placement option 1: hanging to the right

Like your mockup where the pip are weighted to the right:

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i blue.webm -i green.webm -i red.webm -i orange.webm -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[pip1]; \
 [2:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[pip2]; \
 [3:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[pip3]; \
 [0:v][pip1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[bg1]; \
 [bg1][pip2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w*2-20:main_h-overlay_h-10[bg2]; \
 [bg2][pip3]overlay=main_w-overlay_w*3-30:main_h-overlay_h-10,format=yuv420p[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 1 output.mp4
```

## Placement option 2: centered

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i blue.webm -i green.webm -i red.webm -i orange.webm -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[pip1]; \
 [2:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[pip2]; \
 [3:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[pip3]; \
 [0:v][pip1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[bg1]; \
 [bg1][pip2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h-10[bg2]; \
 [bg2][pip3]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10,format=yuv420p[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 1 output.mp4
```

### Notes

- Lanczos [scale algorithm](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html#scaler_005foptions) will probably downscale better than the default.
- The default number of inputs for [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) is 2, but it's best to always use the `inputs` option to avoid the issue you experienced.
- Use a unique name for each output label in the filtergraph.
- If your inputs don't have the same durations then refer to the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) options `eof_action`, `shortest`, etc, to tell it how it should handle any duration discrepencies.
- You can use [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) and omit `-ac` to have more precise control over the downsampling layout.

Comment: Thank you so very much! That worked perfectly! I really really appreciate the info.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again. I tried adding a 4th input file, but it didn't seem to like me using the [bg] alias twice. It gave me error: `Invalid stream specifier: bg.` Alised the 3rd PIP: `[3:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[pip3];` Added another overlay: `[bg][pip3]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-180:main_h-overlay_h-10[v];` Updated amerge: `[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]`. Should I post this as separate question?  Its a bit long here in the comments.

Comment: @Daryl You can edit your question with your new command and the corresponding complete console output. Also, from the answer, "Use a unique name for each output label in the filtergraph". Where do you want the 3rd pip to be placed?

Comment: thank you so very much. I edited the full console and added a image link to show you how I am trying to lay the videos out. Thanks!

Comment: @Daryl What is your preference for the audio: which inputs channels should go to which output channels? What is your desired output channel layout? Mono, stereo?

Comment: I am open to suggestions. I believe I want Mono. I would like to have the audio from all 4 videos played in both headsets at the same time. I don't want audio from one video playing in a different ear than the other video.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Daryl Mono output is easiest and there will be no ambiguity about which channel goes where. Updated answer.

Comment: I want to personally thank you. I've had some really bad experiences when posting questions like this in the past. But you have been kind and offered wonderful suggestions over and over. Thanks a bunch! Your answer totally helped. I guess the problem I was having was due to trying to use the same aliased background for the next overlay. I am not sure why they won't let you use the same alias, but I'm grateful to you for the input. That worked perfectly, and I can see what is needed now to add even more inputs. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Daryl Glad to help. It was a good distraction/procrastination from a boring work task...